# what is the unit cost of arithmetic operators (calculate the model running time)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

i get a problem. maybe it is a simple question, but i cannot find any information about the unit cost of arithmetic cost. so sorry that i am newbie on data structure. thanks for anyone can help.
these source make me confused.

**picture 1:**

[image: picture 1]

the unit cost of "partialSum+=i*i*i" is 1

**picture 2:**

[image: picture 2]

in the second picture, the unit cost of "sum+=A[i]" is 3

the picture 2 said that 1 for +, 1 for = and 1 for [], but why the picture 1 unit cost of "partialSum+=i*i*i" is 1.

Comment: It's doesn't even matter (as long as you don't pick too many zeroes). That's exactly the kind of constant that the big O hides.

Comment: And it's just as well that we can hide these sorts of constant factors behind big O because they can be very variable and hard to predict. The biggest factor these days is the cost of fetching data from memory which can't be found in the cache. This is much higher than the cost of adding two numbers held in registers, and it can be difficult to predict whether a given memory area will end up in cache or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit cost is the execution time of statement like `int i = 0` it take `1` unit time because of initialization. If iterate `i++` nth time then unit cost will be `1` b/c its increment value by `1`

**Note** pre and post increment take's `1` unit time b/c the value is increment by `1` at location pointed by i, we are not adding value form different location suppose address of `i =100;`
`i++` what it do, simply incremnt value at location 100 which is already pointed by i so need to add assignment cost

`sum+=A[i]` took `3` unit cost, lets extend the evaluation `sum =sum+A[i] 1` unit time to extract value for `A[i] 1` unit for `+` and `1` unit for finlly assign

Comment: partialSum += i * i * i <--should this statement take 2 unit cost? because 1 for + and 1 for finally assign.

Comment: @rcm No what about this i*i*i operation for that follow bodmas rule . it took 2 unit cost then 1 for + and 1 for assignment

Comment: "partialSum += i * i * i " is not adding value from different location, so it is a simply increment, right? for example, "int a = 2+3" is 1 unit cost. int a=i / i also is 1. am i correct? @DHARMENDRA SINGH

Comment: @rcm Every Arithmetic operation done between 2 operands and it take 1 unit time so  int a = i/i also neet 2 unit cost 1 for / and another one for = and pre and post are increment and decrement operator

Comment: "partialSum += i * i * i" is 4 unit cost? because +,=,* need 1 unit cost.